# What is the Git trying to show me? Git diff between lines with no perceptible difference. Diff contains � replacement character

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-diff

### Observed Issue

When reviewing commits/differences within a PR before posting in BitBucket Repo I found a number of changes like this:

[image: git diff with no perceptible difference]

I am guessing it has something to do with this replacement character, � (black diamond with a question mark). I'd like to understand what is different between these lines and how to resolve them. There are a good number of these and they are distracting from the functional changes of the PR.

### Updates

As per comments confirmed encoding as UTF-8

As per comments, added a screenshot of how my IDE renders the lines in question:

[image: lines in question as rendered by intellij]

Comment: How does the characters on that file itself look on your local environment, like in your text editor? Does that file have some special encoding?

Comment: It's probably supposed to be a single quote `'`, but from a different encoding or character set, not the regular single quote, and then Bitbucket's UI can't render it properly.

Comment: Looks like I might just do a global find/replace into a commit labeled as "non-functional"

Answer (score 3):

First check your IDE file encoding on your profile.

Then check in git repository how you have set:

example of command to set utf8:

```
git config gui.encoding utf-8
```

for the local repository, of course you can also set this globally by entering:

```
git config --global gui.encoding utf-8
```

**So basically what I am saying try to see if all your parts match the same encoding.**

Answer (score 0):

This isn't Git: it is an encoding issue.

Note that the black-diamond-question-mark symbol is how some systems tell you: *I see some symbol here, but I don't know how to display that symbol.*  Read through Joel Spolsky's article, [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/).  Ironically, this page has one point where the display shows `s–`, which is an ASCII letter s (Unicode [LATIN SMALL LETTER S](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0073/index.htm), U+0073) followed by an "en dash" (Unicode [EN DASH](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm), U+2013, decimal value 8211).  This is the result of taking two ASCII hyphens `-` (Unicode [HYHPEN-MINUS](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/002D/index.htm), U+002D) and combining them into an en dash, which is a feature of many typesetting or markup systems, but which *should not have been applied* to this particular sequence.  It should have been rendered as `s--`, with two hyphens.

In your case, it seems likely that some file has been damaged by attempting to replace simple ASCII characters—probably backquote, Unicode [GRAVE ACCENT](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0060/index.htm), U+0060, and single quote, Unicode [APOSTROPHE](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0027/index.htm), U+0027—with fancy Unicode [LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2018/index.htm) U+2018 and [RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm) U+2019 codes.  However, whatever software that was probably got this transformation wrong and used some other encoding.  Hence your display software is trying to read this alternate encoding *as if* it were a correct UTF-8 encoding of these Unicode code-points, but in fact it's not.

There are many ways for all of this to go wrong, many of which are touched-upon in Spolsky's article.  It's up to you, as a programmer, to figure out what did go wrong and unscrew the inscrutable.